# Is removing \ensuremath the best practice?

Tags: best-practices

First of all, let's see the following dialogue.

> [image]

Generally speaking, is removing `\ensuremath` the best practice?

Comment: no. However, it depends to the surrounding context. Using it in a definition, which can be used only inside math it is indeed superfluous.